# Beep in C# .NET application on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, beep

To debug a firewall delay issue I need an application that will produce a beep on server side when it detects an HTTP GET request.

This code (test.ashx):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="TestHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
        try
        {
            Response.Write("Before beep");
            Console.Beep();
            Response.Write("After beep");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message + "<br />\n" + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

produces sound only when debugging in IIS Express. After moving the web app to IIS, the sound disappears.

Comment: A simple test first: Open the DOS windows, type the command echo _[Ctrl_G]_  (by pressing the Ctrl and G keys) and listen if a sound is produced.

Comment: Have you considered adding proper logging?  One option is log4net https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/ - steep learning curve, but well worth it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three easy ways of producing a sound are [System.Console.Beep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [System.Media.SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and [System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.beep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Unfortunately, these methods only work in desktop applications, and won't work in service applications.  When ASP.Net apps are run under [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) (a desktop app), these sound methods work.  However, when ASP.Net apps are run under the IIS service, the sound methods don't work.

System.Console.Beep() ultimately calls the kernel32.dll [Beep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  It's restricted to desktop apps only (scroll down to the Requirements section).

Same for System.Media.SoundPlayer and System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep().  They call the kernel32.dll [MessageBeep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the winmm.dll [PlaySound()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions, respectively.  They, too, are restricted to desktop apps.

One way to get sounds to play in a service is use [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/).  It's easy to install via NuGet.

This chunk of code is the only way I could get the sound to play.  It has to be played on a separate worker thread, and the execution of the worker thread needs to be paused to let the .wav file finish playing.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

using NAudio.Dsp;
using NAudio.Wave;

...

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var waveFilename = @"c:\Windows\Media\tada.wav";

  /* Trying to play the .wav file on the main thread
     doesn't seem to work. */
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      using (var audioPlayback = new AudioPlayback())
      {
        audioPlayback.Load(waveFilename);
        audioPlayback.Play(); // Asynchronous.

        /* Need to sleep for the approximate length of .wav file,
           otherwise no sound is produced because of the
           asynchronous Play() call. */
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
      }
    });
}
```

Here's the supporting code taken from code in NAudio's NAudioWPFDemo project:

```
public class MaxSampleEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public MaxSampleEventArgs(float minValue, float maxValue)
  {
    this.MaxSample = maxValue;
    this.MinSample = minValue;
  }
  public float MaxSample { get; private set; }
  public float MinSample { get; private set; }
}

public class FftEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public FftEventArgs(Complex[] result)
  {
    this.Result = result;
  }
  public Complex[] Result { get; private set; }
}

public class SampleAggregator : ISampleProvider
{
  // volume
  public event EventHandler<MaxSampleEventArgs> MaximumCalculated;
  private float maxValue;
  private float minValue;
  public int NotificationCount { get; set; }
  int count;

  // FFT
  public event EventHandler<FftEventArgs> FftCalculated;
  public bool PerformFFT { get; set; }
  private readonly Complex[] fftBuffer;
  private readonly FftEventArgs fftArgs;
  private int fftPos;
  private readonly int fftLength;
  private int m;
  private readonly ISampleProvider source;

  private readonly int channels;

  public SampleAggregator(ISampleProvider source, int fftLength = 1024)
  {
    channels = source.WaveFormat.Channels;
    if (!IsPowerOfTwo(fftLength))
      throw new ArgumentException("FFT Length must be a power of two");

    this.m = (int) Math.Log(fftLength, 2.0);
    this.fftLength = fftLength;
    this.fftBuffer = new Complex[fftLength];
    this.fftArgs = new FftEventArgs(fftBuffer);
    this.source = source;
  }

  private bool IsPowerOfTwo(int x)
  {
    return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
  }

  public void Reset()
  {
    count = 0;
    maxValue = minValue = 0;
  }

  private void Add(float value)
  {
    if (PerformFFT && FftCalculated != null)
    {
      fftBuffer[fftPos].X = (float) (value * FastFourierTransform.HammingWindow(fftPos, fftLength));
      fftBuffer[fftPos].Y = 0;
      fftPos++;
      if (fftPos >= fftBuffer.Length)
      {
        fftPos = 0;
        // 1024 = 2^10
        FastFourierTransform.FFT(true, m, fftBuffer);
        FftCalculated(this, fftArgs);
      }
    }

    maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, value);
    minValue = Math.Min(minValue, value);
    count++;
    if (count >= NotificationCount && NotificationCount > 0)
    {
      if (MaximumCalculated != null)
        MaximumCalculated(this, new MaxSampleEventArgs(minValue, maxValue));

      Reset();
    }
  }

  public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return source.WaveFormat; } }

  public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
  {
    var samplesRead = source.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    for (int n = 0; n < samplesRead; n += channels)
      Add(buffer[n + offset]);

    return samplesRead;
  }
}

public class AudioPlayback : IDisposable
{
  private IWavePlayer _playbackDevice;
  private WaveStream _fileStream;

  public void Load(string fileName)
  {
    Stop();
    CloseFile();
    EnsureDeviceCreated();
    OpenFile(fileName);
  }

  private void CloseFile()
  {
    if (_fileStream != null)
    {
      _fileStream.Dispose();
      _fileStream = null;
    }
  }

  private void OpenFile(string fileName)
  {
    try
    {
      var inputStream = new AudioFileReader(fileName);
      _fileStream = inputStream;
      var aggregator = new SampleAggregator(inputStream);
      aggregator.NotificationCount = inputStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate / 100;
      aggregator.PerformFFT = true;
      _playbackDevice.Init(aggregator);
    }
    catch
    {
      CloseFile();
      throw;
    }
  }

  private void EnsureDeviceCreated()
  {
    if (_playbackDevice == null)
      CreateDevice();
  }

  private void CreateDevice()
  {
    _playbackDevice = new WaveOut { DesiredLatency = 200 };
  }

  public void Play()
  {
    if (_playbackDevice != null && _fileStream != null && _playbackDevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Playing)
      _playbackDevice.Play();
  }

  public void Pause()
  {
    if (_playbackDevice != null)
      _playbackDevice.Pause();
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    if (_playbackDevice != null)
      _playbackDevice.Stop();

    if (_fileStream != null)
      _fileStream.Position = 0;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Stop();
    CloseFile();
    if (_playbackDevice != null)
      _playbackDevice.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice that you took the time to explain why the common ways don't work and provided an alternate solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();`